# How correctly to get multiple columns from subquery in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have such SQL query which I make to `PostgreSQL` database. As you can see I'm repeating the same subquery just to get another column. I am convinced that this is ineffective. What is the best way to execute an sql query for your opinion?

```
SELECT
    TABLE_A.COLUMN_1,
    TABLE_A.COLUMN_2,
    (
        SELECT
            TABLE_B.COLUMN_A,
        FROM 
            TABLE_B
        WHERE 
            TABLE_B.COLUMN_Z ILIKE CONCAT('%', TABLE_A.COLUMN_2, '%')
    ) AS COLUMN_3,
    (
        SELECT
            TABLE_B.COLUMN_B,
        FROM 
            TABLE_B
        WHERE 
            TABLE_B.COLUMN_Z ILIKE CONCAT('%', TABLE_A.COLUMN_2, '%')
    ) AS COLUMN_4,
FROM
    TABLE_A
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a lateral join:

```
SELECT a.COLUMN_1, a.COLUMN_2, b.*
FROM TABLE_A a LEFT JOIN LATERAL
     (SELECT b.COLUMN_A, b.COLUMN_B
      FROM TABLE_B b
      WHERE b.COLUMN_Z ILIKE CONCAT('%', a.COLUMN_2, '%')
    ) b
    ON 1=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use join

```
SELECT
    TABLE_A.COLUMN_1,
    TABLE_A.COLUMN_2, TABLE_B.COLUMN_A AS COLUMN_3, ABLE_B.COLUMN_B AS COLUMN_4
FROM
    TABLE_A 
JOIN
    TABLE_B ON TABLE_B.COLUMN_Z LIKE CONCAT('%', TABLE_A.COLUMN_2, '%')
```